# Kotlin - How to pass in the Context parameter for TextToSpeech within a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, text-to-speech

When following tutorials, "this" is used for context however,  "Context! was expected" is the error that pops up. I also tried getActivity(), which gave an unresolved reference. A third option I tried, was Activity which gave the error, " Classifier 'Activity' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here"

[current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMCzM.png)

The goal is to get TextToSpeech to work within the recycler adapter. The main issue that I'm having is what to pass in for the context parameter within the TextToSpeech class.

"  tts = TextToSpeech(this, this )" is what is usually given in tutorials, this does not work within a fragment/recyclerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're inside `onBindViewHolder()`, you can leverage the fact that all instances of `View` have a `context` property:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val context = holder.itemView.context
    // now you can use context anywhere below
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can pass context from MainActivity or Fragment in RecyclerViews onCreateViewHolder

```
//declare context var
private lateinit var context:Context

 @NonNull
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
       ...
        context = parent.context
     ...,
    }
```